# How to change text background color of a button in Android?

Tags: android, android-button

I have searched a lot but I haven't found what I want. What I’m planning to do is to change the background colour of text on a button. I’m not interested in changing the colour on click. I just want to change the background of the text on a button. Thank you.

Edit:
This is a sample. I want to change the black colour if it possible.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/B8tYnEN.png]

Comment: Background of the text on a button or a text color of the button?

Comment: setBackgroundResource(R.color.WhateverColorYouLike); change it like this

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley It is the text background colour.

Comment: @khubaib Is there anyway to set it the xml way?

Comment: please elaborate your question?

Comment: android:textcolor="#ffffff" doesn't work?

Comment: android:background="@android:color/black" is this what you are looking for or change the text color like this android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"

Comment: @Harshid I have added a picture that may help to make my question more clear.

Comment: when black color change.

Comment: please post the xml code

Comment: @khubaib I have added a picture that may help to make my question more clear.

Comment: That will be done by the android:textColor attribute in your xml file for the Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

created this with the help of this,i have correctly positioned the textview on button to acheive this kind of aout put:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffff00"
        android:background="#000000"/>
```

Comment: @Mansour Fahad Mark this as answer if this helped you.

Comment: Perfec solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to set the text color of Button :

```
setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

or

```
android:textColor="@color/white"
```

Use this to set the background of the button :

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_img);
```

or

```
android:background="@drawable/button_img"
```

or

```
android:background="@color/blue"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try to use RelativeLayout instead of Button. Something like this:
`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: How can I set it? Please describe more.

Comment: How you mean how to set it?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the color of the button you can use this android:background="#000fff"

Answer (score 1):

your question is not correctly asked,but what i understood:

to set the background color of text means create shadow of text on button

```
<style name="shadowed_button">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#444444</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">9</item>
</style>
```

and setting shadow programmatically

```
button.setShadowLayer(9, 1, 1, Color.rgb(44, 44, 44));
```

to set the background color of button

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/street_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/layout_a" > <!-- your required color -->
    </Button>

         or

button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

and third thing is onbutton click change background,but you already mentioned that,you don't want that effect.

[image]

no you can not do this with only button widget,you have to create two contols:

```
    button with textView:
set textview background color
 or 
    Image with textView:
set textview background color
 or
create [coumpound control][2]
```

Comment: checkout this answer @Mansour fahad if this solves your problem mark this as answer

Comment: Can you please be more specific. How would I put the text on the button? Should I do the java way or the xml way and how to do it? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) for this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

Place the xml in a file at res/drawable folder i.e. res/drawable/button_text_color.xml. Then just set the drawable as text color:

`android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"`

**All the best**

Comment: Thank you for your help but what I want is to change the background colour of the text.

Comment: pleasure.. But its the best way to show color change during `onClick`.