# How to change Android button click color

Tags: android, button, background

I have one button. I have added background image to my button using background attribute. Now when I click on button, I am not getting the default orange color. How can I get that color.

One more query, In the above scenario how can I change the default orange color to some other color.

Comment: check my answer if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803430/how-to-change-background-image-of-button-when-clicked-focused/7803485#7803485

Comment: search google for "selectors"

Comment: use a selector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771367/create-button-with-rounded-corners-in-android

Comment: Check it out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998718/how-to-change-text-background-color-of-a-button-in-android/18998980#18998980

Answer (score 3):

Try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Style, change state of your button

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your button custom to do that changes for that create an xml file named custom_btn in yoyr drawable folder and paste the code in it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/tick_btn" /> <!-- pressed -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/untick_btn" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

and in the button you have to add `android:button="@drawable/custom_btn"`

Comment: @DownVoter please write comment before downvoting

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="hover color or drawable" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="hover color or drawable" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="color or drawable" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="hover color or drawable" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're just trying to see the "default orange color" then use an ImageButton and apply your drawable to the src (rather than the background). You will then see the native image background behind your image and it will continue to do whatever it was doing before.

Answer (score 0):

**I am not getting the default orange color. How can I get that color.**

> When you add a background to a button it no more remains a default raw button , It becomes a custom button as you have rendered the default behavior by adding some background to it. Now you need to add color to your custom button on your own because the OS deals with only raw buttons not custom.

**How can I change the default orange color to some other color.**

To change the  button state after its pressed can be done in two ways

1) Either add a background image.

2) or Add a xml to the button.

This is a very nice tutorial on [Customizing Android buttons](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-different-buttons-in-android/27747).